How can I recover the object detected by yolov8 in my code?
I need to retrieve the objects detected by my yolo model but I haven't found any command to do so.
I work with this code:
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("/media/aceryohan/_Yohan/Pycharm projects/myfirstproject/computer vision/best.pt")

results = model.track(source=2, show=True, tracker="bytetrack.yaml")

I'm on Lubuntu 22.04 LTS

What do you mean by recover?

Thanks for the quick answer,
I mean I want to use the object(s) detected by yolov8 directly in my python code.

Are you using a segmentation model?

No, I use the default model.
